# Hibernate inner join fetch return nothing if association collection not existed

Tags: hibernate

I have a many-to-one association defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Agent_Assignment", schema = "xxx", catalog = "AAA")
public class AgentAssignment {
    private Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> attributes = new HashSet<AgentAssignmentAttr>();

...

    @OneToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true )
    @JoinColumn(name="Agent_Assignment_GUID")
    public Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Agent_Assignment_Attr", schema = "xxx", catalog = "AAA")
public class AgentAssignmentAttr {
...
}
```

And then and HQL statement defined as follow to load both objects:

```
"from AgentAssignment agtasgn inner join fetch agtasgn.attributes where agtasgn.conversationGuid = :conversationGuid"
```

The issue is that if there are no corresponding row of AgentAssignmentAttr existed in table  "Agent_Assignment_Attr" that matches the join column of "Agent_Assignment_GUID", then it would return no results, even though there's a row in the primary table "Agent_Assignment" that would match the condition in the where statements.

I would expect the behavior to be that Hibernate would returns the AgentAssignment object which matches the "where" condition with the collection set of AgentAssignmentAttr being empty.

If anybody who experienced the same issue can provide some pointers on how to resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's how inner joins work. What you describe is a left join.